Implementing pong with DQN, using feature vectors not pixels in python. is my code for implementing a DQNA correct as my model is not training well
I'm working on implementing a reinforcement learning (RL) environment for a Pong game using OpenAI's Gym. The goal is to train an AI agent to play Pong by controlling the paddle.
The agent receives too many negative rewards, even when it seems to be moving correctly. Specifically, the reward function penalizes the agent for moving away from the ball, but this happens too frequently and seems to occur even when the ball is moving towards the paddle.
Observation Space: The observation space includes the positions and speeds of the ball and paddles, the distance between the ball and paddles, and the paddle speeds.
Action Space: The action space consists of three discrete actions: move up, move down, and stay still.
Reward Function: The reward function rewards the agent for hitting the ball and penalizes it for missing the ball or moving away from it.
How can I adjust the reward function to only penalize the agent when it moves away from the ball while the ball is moving towards the paddle? or there any other problems with my game's logic or DQNA implementation? Any suggestions on improving the training performance would be greatly appreciated.
Following is my code for DQNA:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
import random
from collections import deque

class DQNAgent:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=10000)  # Increased replay memory size
        self.gamma = 0.99    # Increased discount rate
        self.epsilon = 1.0  # Exploration rate
        self.epsilon_min = 0.01
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.995  # Slower epsilon decay
        self.learning_rate = 0.001  # Slightly increased learning rate
        self.model = self._build_model()
        self.target_model = self._build_model()
        self.update_target_model()

    def _build_model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Input(shape=(self.state_size,)))  # Added Input layer to define the input shape
        model.add(Dense(48, activation='relu'))  # Increased neurons to 48
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Dropout layer for regularization
        model.add(Dense(48, activation='relu'))  # Increased neurons to 48
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Dropout layer for regularization
        model.add(Dense(48, activation='relu'))  # Increased neurons to 48
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Dropout layer for regularization
        model.add(Dense(48, activation='relu'))  # Increased neurons to 48
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Dropout layer for regularization
        model.add(Dense(48, activation='relu'))  # Increased neurons to 48
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Dropout layer for regularization
        model.add(Dense(48, activation='relu'))  # Increased neurons to 48
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Dropout layer for regularization
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate))
        return model

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    def act(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return np.random.randint(self.action_size)
        else:
            act_values = self.model.predict(state)
            return np.argmax(act_values[0])

    def replay(self, batch_size):
        if len(self.memory) < batch_size:
            return 0  # Not enough memory to sample
        minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
        total_loss = 0
        for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
            target = reward
            if not done:
                target = (reward + self.gamma *
                          np.amax(self.target_model.predict(next_state)[0]))
            target_f = self.model.predict(state)
            target_f[0][action] = target
            history = self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
            total_loss += history.history['loss'][0]
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
        return total_loss / batch_size  # Return average loss

    def update_target_model(self):
        # Copy weights from model to target_model
        self.target_model.set_weights(self.model.get_weights())

    def save(self, filename):
        self.model.save(f"{filename}.keras")

    def load(self, filename):
        self.model = load_model(f"{filename}")
        self.target_model = self._build_model()
        self.update_target_model()

Following is my Code for Pong logic:
import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
import pygame
from pygame.locals import K_w, K_s

class PongEnv(gym.Env):
    metadata = {'render.modes': ['human']}

    def __init__(self):
        super(PongEnv, self).__init__()

        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.ball_speed = 7
        self.paddle_speed = 12
        self.ball = pygame.Rect(self.width // 2 - 15, self.height // 2 - 15, 30, 30)
        self.player_paddle = pygame.Rect(self.width - 20, self.height // 2 - 70, 10, 140)
        self.ai_paddle = pygame.Rect(10, self.height // 2 - 70, 10, 140)
        self.ball_dx, self.ball_dy = self.ball_speed, self.ball_speed
        self.player_paddle_speed = 0  # Initialize player paddle speed

        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3)
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(13,), dtype=np.float32)  # Updated shape

    def reset(self):
        self.ball.center = (self.width // 2, self.height // 2)
        self.player_paddle.centery = self.height // 2
        self.ai_paddle.centery = self.height // 2
        self.ball_dx, self.ball_dy = self.ball_speed, self.ball_speed
        self.player_paddle_speed = 0  # Reset player paddle speed
        return self.get_state()

    def get_state(self):
        distance_ball_player = self.ball.centery - self.player_paddle.centery
        distance_ball_ai = self.ball.centery - self.ai_paddle.centery
        state = [
            self.player_paddle.centery,
            self.ai_paddle.centery,
            self.ball.centerx,
            self.ball.centery,
            self.ball_dx,
            self.ball_dy,  # Adding ball's vertical speed
            distance_ball_player,  # Adding distance between ball and player paddle
            distance_ball_ai,  # Adding distance between ball and AI paddle
            self.player_paddle.top,
            self.player_paddle.bottom,
            self.ai_paddle.top,
            self.ai_paddle.bottom,
            self.player_paddle_speed,  # Adding player paddle speed
        ]
        return np.array(state, dtype=np.float32)

    def step(self, action):
        reward = 0
        done = False

        previous_player_paddle_position = self.player_paddle.centery  # Track previous position

        # Move player paddle
        if action == 0:
            self.player_paddle.centery -= self.paddle_speed
        elif action == 1:
            self.player_paddle.centery += self.paddle_speed

        # Ensure paddle stays within the screen
        if self.player_paddle.top < 0:
            self.player_paddle.top = 0
        if self.player_paddle.bottom > self.height:
            self.player_paddle.bottom = self.height

        # Calculate player paddle speed
        self.player_paddle_speed = self.player_paddle.centery - previous_player_paddle_position

        # Move the ball
        self.ball.x += self.ball_dx
        self.ball.y += self.ball_dy

        # Ball collision with top or bottom
        if self.ball.top <= 0 or self.ball.bottom >= self.height:
            self.ball_dy *= -1

        # Ball collision with paddles
        if self.ball.colliderect(self.player_paddle):
            self.ball_dx *= -1
            reward += 5  # Reward for hitting the ball with the paddle
            print(f"Ball hit by player paddle. Reward: {reward}")
        elif self.ball.colliderect(self.ai_paddle):
            self.ball_dx *= -1

        # Check for out of bounds
        if self.ball.left <= 0:
            done = True
            reward += 10  # Reward for scoring
            print(f"Ball out of left bounds. Reward: {reward}")
        elif self.ball.right >= self.width:
            done = True
            reward -= 10  # Penalty for opponent scoring
            print(f"Ball out of right bounds. Penalty: {reward}")

        # AI paddle movement
        if self.ai_paddle.centery < self.ball.centery:
            self.ai_paddle.centery += self.paddle_speed
        if self.ai_paddle.centery > self.ball.centery:
            self.ai_paddle.centery -= self.paddle_speed

        # Ensure AI paddle stays within the screen
        if self.ai_paddle.top < 0:
            self.ai_paddle.top = 0
        if self.ai_paddle.bottom > self.height:
            self.ai_paddle.bottom = self.height

        # Reward for moving towards the ball and penalty for moving away
        if self.ball_dx > 0:  # Ball moving towards the player paddle
            if (action == 0 and self.player_paddle.centery > self.ball.centery) or (action == 1 and self.player_paddle.centery < self.ball.centery):
                reward += 0.5
                print(f"Player paddle moving towards ball. Reward: {reward}")
            else:
                reward -= 0.5  # Penalty for moving away from the ball
                print(f"Player paddle moving away from ball. Penalty: {reward}")

        next_state = self.get_state()
        return next_state, reward, done, {}

    def render(self, mode='human'):
        if mode == 'human':
            pygame.init()
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.player_paddle)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.ai_paddle)
            pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.ball)
            pygame.draw.aaline(screen, (255, 255, 255), (self.width // 2, 0), (self.width // 2, self.height))
            pygame.display.flip() 

